# How to use multiprocessing in julia to create subplots?

Tags: matplotlib, multiprocessing, julia

Previously I use each process to create one figure. As there are too many figures, it is better to arrange these figures in subplots for better comparison.

I first tried this

```
using Distributed
@everywhere using PyPlot

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 4)
pmap(i-> begin
ax[i].scatter([i, 2], [3, 4])
end, 1:4)

fig.savefig("test.png", transparent=false)
```

It just generate empty subplots. I understood later that it is because `ax` is copied for each process and does not share between processes.

I then tried `SharedArrays` to share `ax`

```
using SharedArrays
convert(SharedArray, ax)
```

and got

```
ArgumentError: type of SharedArray elements must be bits types, got PyCall.PyObject
```

The final solution would be to move plotting out of each process and collect data instead.

However I am still curious if there is any way to create figures (or subplots) at each process and collect them in the end?

Answer (score 2):

Use PyPlot via Plots.jl for this. Plots.jl allows for construction of layout from previously generated plots.

```
using Distributed
addprocs(4)
@everywhere using Plots
@everywhere pyplot()

pp = pmap(i -> plot(rand(10).+myid()), 1:4)
plot(pp...)
```

(note each plot on this exapmple has the y-scale corresponding to worker's id)

[image]